# Williams Alligator strategy in Pinescript 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to learn pine script for the first time, and managed to get through the basics. Part of the exercise, I am trying to build a script for the William Alligator strategy but I am unable to plot the graph, and below is the same code. Can anyone please suggest if anything wrong with my script? Thanks!

//Aligator

//Aligator

```
lipsLength  = input.int(200, "Lips Length")
teethLength = input.int(8, "Teeth Length")
jawLength   = input.int(13, "Jaw Length")
lipsOffset  = input.int(0, "Lips Offset")
teethOffset = input.int(0, "Teeth Offset")
jawOffset   = input.int(7, "Jaw Offset")
jaw = ta.sma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = ta.sma(hl2, teethLength)
lips = ta.sma(hl2, lipsLength)

plot(lipsl)
plot(jawl)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed after a little bit of research, but still, the graphs are not plotted accurately when backtested.

Here is the latest code

//Aligator

```
lipsLength  = input.int(200, "Lips Length")
teethLength = input.int(8, "Teeth Length")
jawLength   = input.int(13, "Jaw Length")
lipsOffset  = input.int(0, "Lips Offset")
teethOffset = input.int(0, "Teeth Offset")
jawOffset   = input.int(7, "Jaw Offset")
jaw = ta.sma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = ta.sma(hl2, teethLength)
lips = ta.sma(hl2, lipsLength)
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to incoporate your new sma additions. Take care

Answer (score 0):

These 3 lines here - we cannot use a variable already defined in another input this way:

```
lipsl       = input.int(hl2, lipsLength)
teethl      = input.int(hl2, teethLength)
jawl        = input.int(hl2, jawLength)
```

These are invalid uses of a user input variables as lipsLength, teethLength, and jawLength are defined by inputs. Try referring to the reference manual for inputs to see required arguments.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Inputs.html

Cheers my friend.

**EDIT**

Please see the adapted code applying your values to plots using your offset inputs in the offset arguments of the plot functions complete with titles and color.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", overlay=true)

lipsLength  = input.int(200, "Lips Length")
teethLength = input.int(8, "Teeth Length")
jawLength   = input.int(13, "Jaw Length")
lipsOffset  = input.int(0, "Lips Offset")
teethOffset = input.int(0, "Teeth Offset")
jawOffset   = input.int(7, "Jaw Offset")

jaw   = ta.sma(hl2, jawLength)
teeth = ta.sma(hl2, teethLength)
lips  = ta.sma(hl2, lipsLength)

plot(jaw  , "jaw"  , color.red,   offset=jawOffset)
plot(teeth, "teeth", color.blue,  offset=teethOffset)
plot(lips , "lips" , color.green, offset=lipsOffset)
```

Cheers